# SQL query not returning multiple results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am pretty new to SQL and trying to get a SQL query that should return results for multiple days. It wil however only return data for one of the selected days instead of all the dates. I have tried removing the "DISTINCT" statement but then it just returns multiple repeating results, but all for the same day once again. Any suugestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
declare @Check_Date smalldatetime
set @Check_Date =  convert(varchar(8),  DATEADD( DAY , -3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ), 112)

SELECT
     DISTINCT [SIS].[dbo].[Stores].[StoreNbr] AS 'Store'
    ,[SIS].[dbo].[Stores].[StoreName] AS 'Name'
    ,[SIS].[dbo].[STORE_CALENDAR].[TRXN_DATE] AS 'Date'
    ,case when [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_POLLING_EXCEPTIONS].[REASON_MISSED] is null then substring([SIS].[dbo].[STORE_POLLING_EXCEPTIONS].[REASON_MISSED],1,49) else 'Not Yet Polled' end  as 'Reason Missed'

FROM
    [SIS].[dbo].[DAILY_TOTALS], [SIS].[dbo].[Stores], [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_POLLING_EXCEPTIONS], [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_CALENDAR]

WHERE
    [SIS].[dbo].[DAILY_TOTALS].[STORE_NUMBER] = [SIS].[dbo].[Stores].[StoreNbr] 
    AND [SIS].[dbo].[DAILY_TOTALS].[TRXN_DATE] = @Check_Date
    AND [SIS].[dbo].[DAILY_TOTALS].[TRXN_DATE] = [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_CALENDAR].[TRXN_DATE]
    AND [SIS].[dbo].[DAILY_TOTALS].[NET_SALES_AMOUNT] IS NULL
    AND [SIS].[dbo].[Stores].[StoreNbr] IN (
        SELECT [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_CALENDAR].[StoreNbr]
        FROM [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_CALENDAR]
        WHERE [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_CALENDAR].[TRXN_DATE] = @Check_Date
        )
    AND [SIS].[dbo].[Stores].[StoreNbr] IN (
        SELECT [SIS].[dbo].[Stores].[StoreNbr]
        FROM [SIS].[dbo].[Stores]
        WHERE [SIS].[dbo].[Stores].[ClosingOps] IS NULL
        )
    AND [SIS].[dbo].[Stores].[StoreNbr] NOT IN (
        SELECT [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_POLLING_EXCEPTIONS].[STORE_NUMBER]
        FROM [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_POLLING_EXCEPTIONS]
        WHERE [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_POLLING_EXCEPTIONS].[TRXN_DATE] = @Check_Date
        AND [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_POLLING_EXCEPTIONS].[REASON_MISSED] IS NOT NULL
        )

UNION ALL

SELECT
     DISTINCT [SIS].[dbo].[Stores].[StoreNbr] AS 'Store'
    ,[SIS].[dbo].[Stores].[StoreName] AS 'Name'
    ,[SIS].[dbo].[STORE_CALENDAR].[TRXN_DATE] AS 'Date'
    ,[SIS].[dbo].[STORE_POLLING_EXCEPTIONS].[REASON_MISSED] AS 'Reason Missed'

FROM
    [SIS].[dbo].[DAILY_TOTALS], [SIS].[dbo].[Stores], [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_POLLING_EXCEPTIONS], [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_CALENDAR]

WHERE
    [SIS].[dbo].[DAILY_TOTALS].[STORE_NUMBER] = [SIS].[dbo].[Stores].[StoreNbr] 
    AND [SIS].[dbo].[Stores].[StoreNbr] = [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_POLLING_EXCEPTIONS].[STORE_NUMBER]
    AND [SIS].[dbo].[DAILY_TOTALS].[TRXN_DATE] = @Check_Date  
    AND [SIS].[dbo].[DAILY_TOTALS].[TRXN_DATE] = [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_CALENDAR].[TRXN_DATE]
    AND [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_POLLING_EXCEPTIONS].[TRXN_DATE] = @Check_Date
    AND [SIS].[dbo].[DAILY_TOTALS].[NET_SALES_AMOUNT] IS NULL
    AND [SIS].[dbo].[Stores].[StoreNbr] IN (
        SELECT [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_CALENDAR].[StoreNbr]
        FROM [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_CALENDAR]
        WHERE [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_CALENDAR].[TRXN_DATE] = @Check_Date
        )
    AND [SIS].[dbo].[Stores].[StoreNbr] IN (
        SELECT [SIS].[dbo].[Stores].[StoreNbr]
        FROM [SIS].[dbo].[Stores]
        WHERE [SIS].[dbo].[Stores].[ClosingOps] IS NULL
        )

ORDER BY 'Date', 'Store'
```

Comment: Table aliases will make your code much easier to read. For example: `SELECT a.Col1 FROM Table1 a WHERE a.col2 = 'dog'`  You can use more meaningful aliases, but the point is that `[SIS].[dbo].[DAILY_TOTALS].[TRXN_DATE]` is ugly compared to `a.Trxn_Date`.  Your query will also be much easier to analyze if you don't use deprecated join syntax (comma separated listing of tables), instead: `SELECT a.Col1, b.Col2 FROM Table1 a JOIN Table2 b ON a.ID = b.ID`

Comment: Your queries both have `AND [SIS].[dbo].[DAILY_TOTALS].[TRXN_DATE] = @Check_Date` -- that is a (assuming no time stamps) a single date condition.  What conditions do you want to apply to your date to include multiple dates?  Do your `trxn_date` values have a timestamp, or is just a date?  You could (per the comment above really clean this up), and we'll help if you need it, but you need to tell us a lot more about the data we're dealing with, and your expected results.

Comment: This is alot of query and we are not sure of your data and schema requirements. Can you simplify this and give us just some example data and what you are expecting to find?

Comment: Also this: `case when [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_POLLING_EXCEPTIONS].[REASON_MISSED] is null then substring([SIS].[dbo].[STORE_POLLING_EXCEPTIONS].[REASON_MISSED],1,49) else 'Not Yet Polled' end  as 'Reason Missed'`  - if it's null, you can't substring it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I tried and actions taken to try and understand problem:

1. Aliased tables
2. case is null and then a sub string (perhasp you
   mean not is null..
3. Replaced antiquated but still valid joins with
   INNER/OUTER join syntax.
4. Found no way to join SPE to other records...Assume it's somehow on store...
5. Found joins may be
   limiting results... Perhaps you really want outer joins (all stores
   and then existing transaction dates and reaons missed... Adjusted joins so all stores would be returned; regardless.
6. Found limiting criteria on Daily Totals may be part of the problem;
   also a reason why outer joins are being used.
7. assume query is only interested in results which have a net_Sales_Amount of null all
   other data will be omitted.
8. eliminated redundant sub query on store_calender checking against @check_date as I've moved date check to the outer join which will only return records for store
   numbers matching that date; but not eliminate stores as it currently
   is doing.
9. as all tables are now properly joined (Assuming we can
   figure out store polling exceptions join) no need for sub query to
   find out if closing ops is null    simply made it part of the
   criteria.
10. Case statement in select is off.  Howe can you check for null and then parse a string from a null value.  Assumed NOT null is needed..
11. not sure what to do with 3rd subselect (now
    only one left)  seems like you're excluding ALL stores that had a reason_Missed populated for the date in question.. Yet the case statement exists.... it would always be null so either the case is wrong or the sub query is.  (so not sure what proper action is)
12. Stopped here.. Didn't want to spend time on 2nd query until the first one was figured out correctly.

All in all to figure this out we'd need to know

1. Table structures for relevant tables and columns and relationships
2. Example data for each
3. Mockup of expected results (Consider using SQL Fiddle to build out a template for people to help you with)
4. Plain text English of the desired results.  I want to see all stores missed transactions and reasons for a specific date.... or what?  If you can't put it into words, then you don't know what you want yet.

As to why you're not seeing data:

- Where clause criteria is limiting results in a way I don't think you want
- Join criteria relating tables is not using outer joins thereby eliminating data I think you want
- Missing join is creating a Cartesian product which is being hidden by your other limiting data, which may cause other problems later.

.

```
SELECT
     S.[StoreNbr] AS 'Store'
    ,S.[StoreName] AS 'Name'
    ,SC.[TRXN_DATE] AS 'Date'
    ,case when SPE.[REASON_MISSED] is not null then 
       substring(SPE.[REASON_MISSED],1,49) 
       else 'Not Yet Polled' end  as 'Reason Missed'

FROM [SIS].[dbo].[DAILY_TOTALS] DT 
RIGHT JOIN [SIS].[dbo].[Stores] S
  ON  DT.[STORE_NUMBER] = S.[StoreNbr] 
LEFT JOIN [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_CALENDAR] SC
  ON  DT.[TRXN_DATE] = SC.[TRXN_DATE]
  and DT.[TRXN_DATE] = @Check_Date
LEFT JOIN [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_POLLING_EXCEPTIONS] SPE 
  ON S.[StoreNbr] = SPE.[Store_Number] --This likely wrong but no associations identified.
  and SC.[TRXN_DATE] = SPE.[TRXN_DATE] --Perhaps this is needed as well?


WHERE DT.[NET_SALES_AMOUNT] IS NULL
    AND S.[ClosingOps] IS NULL
/*  What's this do?

    AND S.[StoreNbr] NOT IN (
        SELECT [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_POLLING_EXCEPTIONS].[STORE_NUMBER]
        FROM [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_POLLING_EXCEPTIONS]
        WHERE [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_POLLING_EXCEPTIONS].[TRXN_DATE] = @Check_Date
        AND [SIS].[dbo].[STORE_POLLING_EXCEPTIONS].[REASON_MISSED] IS NOT NULL
        )
```

*/
    --- REST OF QUERY OMITTED UNTIL THE FIRST PART IS WORKING NO POINT THINKING ABOUT THE NEXT.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it certanly shortened up the SQL statement. I ended up just finding out that the issue was that I was missing the ">" in the date check section. Once I added that in it did exactly what I was looking for. I am planning on taking the suggestions to clean it up a little though. Thanks :-)